# $max aggregation not showing my desired output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is the updated version of `$max`. I have tried out this code of your.

```
db.contact.aggregate([
   {$sort: {machine_Id: 1, date:1}},
   {$group:{
      _id: '$machine_Id',
      max_air_Temp: {$max:"$air_Temp"}
     }
   }
  ], function(err, meibanlist) {
      if (err || !meibanlist ) console.log("Record not found");
      else meibanlist.forEach (function(machine_Id){
          console.log(machine_Id);
      })
});
```

but when i ran that in mongodb, it gave me:

```
{ _id: 5, max_air_Temp: 819 }
{ _id: 857, max_air_Temp: 121 }
{ _id: 52, max_air_Temp: 146 }
{ _id: 67, max_air_Temp: 300 }
{ _id: 655, max_air_Temp: 84 }
{ _id: 15, max_air_Temp: 844 }
{ _id: 363, max_air_Temp: 861 }
{ _id: 717, max_air_Temp: 623 }
{ _id: 189, max_air_Temp: 639 }
{ _id: 346, max_air_Temp: 563 }
{ _id: 470, max_air_Temp: 804 }
{ _id: 917, max_air_Temp: 697 }
{ _id: 167, max_air_Temp: 438 }
{ _id: 4, max_air_Temp: 467 }
```

But when i tried this code:

```
db.contact.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "machine_Id", max: {$max: "$air_Temp"}}}], 
  function(err, meibanlist) {
    if (err || !meibanlist) console.log("Record not found");
    else meibanlist.forEach (function(machine_Id){
      console.log(machine_Id);
    })
  });
```

it showed me this output: This output is more similar to what i want because it shows me only one output but i would want the `'machine_id'` to show the exact id rather than the word `machine_id`. Do you know how to edit this set?

output:

```
{ _id: 'machine_Id', max: 997 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In aggregate query and use `_id: '$machine_Id'` instead of `_id: 'machine_Id'`

```
db.contact.aggregate([
   {$sort: {machine_Id: 1, date:1}},
   {$group:{
      _id: '$machine_Id',
      max_air_Temp: {$max:"$air_Temp"}
     }
   }
  ], function(err, meibanlist) {
      if (err || !meibanlist ) console.log("Record not found");
      else meibanlist.forEach (function(machine_Id){
          console.log(machine_Id);
      })
});
```

**Update:** According to your new requirement you may want only one output that `air_Temp` value is maximum with `machine_id` as `_id`.

so can try it

```
db.contact.aggregate([
   {$sort: {air_Temp: -1}},
   {$limit:1},
   {$project:{_id:"$machine_Id",max_air_Temp:"$air_Temp" }}
  ], function(err, meibanlist) {
        if (err || !meibanlist ) console.log("Record not found");
        else meibanlist.forEach (function(machine_Id){
           console.log(machine_Id);
     })
});
```

Comment: When i ran your code, it gave me the answer(see above). what i was looking for is just 1 output instead of all the records that i have.

Comment: still the same output though

Comment: output should be like `{ _id: '22', max_air_Temp: 997 } { _id: '23', max_air_Temp: 897 }` no need `$project` stage

Comment: ive updated the question. the second set of codes are closer to my desired answer than the first one. But i dont know how to change the machine_id to become the numbered machine_id. Ive tried adding "", $ and ' but none worked

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! thanks so much. Ill review it again. Thanks. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/).

Replace

```
_id: 'machine_Id',
```

with

```
_id: '$machine_Id',
```

Comment: ive tried this before but it gave me the output of all the air_temp instead of 1 output only which i want